# Spring java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am having a session management issue in my spring application, here is the scenario.
When a user opens my app URL it'll ask for credentials and logs in. After the user looged in and if he open a new tab and paste my app URL it'll ask for credentials again and user logs in.

Now if the user logs out in tab1 and if user wants to performs any operation in second tab user gets an error with below stacktrace and logs out.

```
Oct 10, 2014 3:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CollPortal] in context with path [/CollPortal] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2886)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2316)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:910)
    at com.dc.core.common.FlashRecyclingFilter.doFilterInternal(FlashRecyclingFilter.java:22)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.dc.core.common.StripJSessionIdFilter.doFilter(StripJSessionIdFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is my `FlashRecyclingFilter`

```
@Component
public class FlashRecyclingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
    IFlash flash = new Flash(request.getSession());
    flash.recycle();
    }
}
```

How do I make sure user should be able to perform operations in one tab when the user is logged out in another tab? Can anyone please help me with my issue?

Comment: Well "fix your code" would be a valid answer. Don't know what `FlashRecyclingFilter` is doing, but the error is there. Spring's Security probably sent a redirect to login page and your filter is trying to store something on the session, which does not exist. Check [HttpServletRequest#getSession(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29).

Comment: @PavelHoral I updated the question with `FlashRecyclingFilter` Its just trying to get `session` from `request`

Comment: Make the filter as no-op when there is no session. I.e. use `getSession(false)` and skip the code if you get null.

Comment: Posted my comment as an actual answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What happens is that Spring probably sends redirect to the login page, while your custom filter tries to create session (which can not be done as the response has been already sent).

You should modify your filter so that it does not eagerly create the session on its own:

```
super.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
    IFlash flash = new Flash(session);
    flash.recycle();
}
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, I have faced the same issue. Could you please tell me how can I get the IFlash, Flash class (belongs to which API)?. Thanks.

Comment: These are OP's components AFAIK.

Comment: Can someone please tell us exactly what's the API of IFlash ? because I have looked for it for a long time

Comment: @Shessuky I guess that is some custom class/interface possible created by OP and kind of irrelevant in the question.

Answer (score -4):

Check whether you have used the rd.forward() or rd.include(). we have to use rd.include() to resolve that error. try with that once.

Comment: What the heck is `rd`?

Comment: it stands for RequestDispatcher, a thing we use to send data from servlets to jsp or html files or something like that