# Struts 2: Impossible get session after response is commited

Tags: spring-boot, struts2, tomcat8

I've already read the [another article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343666/spring-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-respon) about it but it doesn't help me to find a generic solution for the entire application.

I've kept a big legacy web application (Struts2, Spring Boot, and Tomcat embedded) and I'm facing these following error.

```
2018-08-14 11:01:11.872 [http-nio-10010-exec-114] ERROR   o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp] - Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2953)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2367)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:896)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:537)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.initialize(PageContextImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalGetPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.errorPage_jsp._jspService(errorPage_jsp.java:127)
```

Other example:

```
2018-08-14 11:01:11.870 [http-nio-10010-exec-114] ERROR   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.q.q.c.RedirectResourceServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [com.mydomain.myapplication.control.RedirectResourceServlet] in context with path [] threw exceptionjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2953)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2367)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240)
```

It occurs in different places like *Actions.java and JSP files.

Does someone know how and which is the best approach to intercept all `request.getSession()` to check if it was already committed? And how could I in a Struts 2 context create a new session? The `request.getSession(true)` doesn't work when the `response.isCommitted()` is true.

I've already tried to create a @WebFilter where I check and try to create a new session, but it doesn't work as expected. I also believe it is not the best approach.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class SessionValidatorFilter implements Filter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (servletResponse.isCommitted() && servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest && servletResponse instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            logger.debug("Response was already committed. Trying to create a new session.");
            try {
                HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getSession(true);
                if (session != null)
                    logger.debug("Session created.");
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("Error trying to create new Session.");
            }
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll happen because session uses first level cache and it uses client browser memory when client redirects and send a request again from the same page after session expires then request send due to save in his memory. If you want the things to work right for you then you must avoid caching and use javascript.

Comment: I don't think I could change all pages. It has about 1200 JSP pages. Do you know if there is a way to intercept requests to verify it?